# Get the first substring by regex match method

Tags: regex

I have the below string `https://xxx.xxx/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-zzz-zzzz`

I have to match the substring `https://xxx.xxx/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-`

Please help me to get it by regex match method

Thank you so much !!!

Comment: try `https?:\/\/[x.\/-]+`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: pls post the actual url and expected output, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want only the text before the word, which is before the last hyphen of the url, try this regex

`.+-(?=.+-)`

Output:

[image]

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8dKJs1/1)

tell me if its okay for you...

Answer (score 0):

You could try pattern:

```
^https:\/\/[^\/]+\/(?:[^-]+-){5}
```

Pattern explanation:

`^` - match beginning of the string

`https:\/\/` - match `https://` literally

`[^\/]+` - match one or more character other than `/`

`\/` - match `/` literally

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`[^-]+-` - match one or more of other character than `-` and then match `-` literally

`{5}` - match preceeding pattern 5 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WbGmQ/1)